# Local time from free API

Tags: api, time

I use google api to get the weather and in the response I get the local time as well, but it is way off and not the right time.

**Is there a time api by Google or anything else that is free?**

This is what I use now:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=hong kong

  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <xml_api_reply version="1">
- <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
- <forecast_information>
      <city data="hong kong" /> 
      <postal_code data="hong kong" /> 
      <latitude_e6 data="" /> 
      <longitude_e6 data="" /> 
      <forecast_date data="2011-06-12" /> 
      <current_date_time data="2011-06-12 22:30:00 +0000" /> 
      <unit_system data="US" /> 
  </forecast_information>
- <current_conditions>
      <condition data="Partly Cloudy" /> 
      <temp_f data="86" /> 
      <temp_c data="30" /> 
      <humidity data="Humidity: 70%" /> 
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif" /> 
      <wind_condition data="Wind: S at 12 mph" /> 
  </current_conditions>
- <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Sun" /> 
      <low data="81" /> 
      <high data="84" /> 
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_rain.gif" /> 
      <condition data="Chance of Rain" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
- <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
      <low data="81" /> 
      <high data="84" /> 
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif" /> 
      <condition data="Partly Sunny" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
- <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Tue" /> 
      <low data="81" /> 
      <high data="84" /> 
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_storm.gif" /> 
      <condition data="Chance of Storm" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
- <forecast_conditions>
      <day_of_week data="Wed" /> 
      <low data="81" /> 
      <high data="84" /> 
      <icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_storm.gif" /> 
      <condition data="Chance of Storm" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
  </weather>
  </xml_api_reply>
```

Comment: It is not the local time. If you see the time is "2011-06-12 22:30:00 +0000" where +0000 represent it is GMT +00:00 You can convert it to your local time by adding the offset.

Comment: where can i get the offset from? it is not there in the returned xml

Answer (score 1):

It is not the current time. It is the date and time of the **last weather update** for that location.  You'll notice that as time continues on (at a constant) the value returned stays the same.

You don't need an API to get the local time for someone's computer. Just ask them yourself.

```
<script language='javascript' >
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>")
</script>
```

Or if this is on the server just use your programming language to ask the server for the local time.

Comment: I smiled at 'ask them yourself', but anyway seems it's the only way. +1